# MSG to TF : Quaternion Not Properly Normalized

Tags: imu, ros-melodic, transform, quaternion

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you for clicking, hello, I'm ros begginer.
I am currently using IMU for Slam mapping. But I get the ERR MSG(MSG to TF : Quaternion Not Properly Normalized).
What should I do??

```
$ rostopic echo /imu_data
header:
  seq: 122552
  stamp:
  secs: 1626158167
  nsecs: 547560799
  frame_id: "imu_link"
orientation:
  x: 126.18
  y: -40.61
  z: -174.65
  w: -40.63
orientation_covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
angular_velocity:
  x: 2.20086018676
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
angular_velocity_covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
linear_acceleration:
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
linear_acceleration_covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/382317/msg-to-tf-:-quaternion-not-properly-normalized/) by [jjb1220](https://answers.ros.org/users/77129/jjb1220/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2021-07-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We see this in your `rostopic echo` output:

> ```
> orientation:
> ```

```
  x: 126.18
  y: -40.61
  z: -174.65
  w: -40.63
```

Is this coming from your IMU?

`orientation` is supposed to be a quaternion.

From [the documentation](http://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Imu.html):

```
Header header
geometry_msgs/Quaternion orientation
...
```

Values typically lie in `[0, 1]`. I'm not sure what to make of the values in your `orientation` field.

Are you setting it to Euler angles perhaps? That won't work.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jjb1220](https://answers.ros.org/users/77129/jjb1220/) on 2021-07-14**:
oh thank you, The value I have is the orientation value. Can I replace this value with a Quaternion value??

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-07-14**:
If you have a quaternion, you could use it to populate the field.

If you don't have a quaternion, but an Euler triplet, you could convert it to a quaternion [using one of the available methods](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Quaternions).

**Comment by [jjb1220](https://answers.ros.org/users/77129/jjb1220/) on 2021-07-15**:
very Thank, I fixed it!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-07-15**:
What was your solution?

**Comment by [jjb1220](https://answers.ros.org/users/77129/jjb1220/) on 2021-07-15**:
As a result, the above article did not fix it. I just got a hint. lol
I republished the values ​​provided by the IMU sensor I use according to the topic msg format.